# about json_encode and ajax dataType: "json"

Tags: php, javascript, json

In my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: CI_ROOT + "isUserExist",
        type: "GET",
        data: {recepient: recepient},
        success: function(r) {
            console.log(r)
        }
})
```

Gives me an output **[{"records":"1"}][{"records":"1"}]** So I parsed it to json by adding **dataType: "json"** in my ajax code. But when I parsed it, it doesn't give me output but error on try-catch-block.

How do I get it to display as objects?
In my PHP code, I'm doing it this way:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
     echo json_encode($this->searchmodel->doesUsersExists($matches[0][$i]));
 } //gets the user id of the user from a given string.
```

Answer (score 5):

Add each entry to an array and then json encode that array, instead of json encoding each one separately.  If you only have one call to json_encode, you will get valid JSON:

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
     $result[] = $this->searchmodel->doesUsersExists($matches[0][$i]);
} //gets the user id of the user from a given string.

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not valid JSON. Make an array from your exist results and encode *that*.