# json_encode creating a malformed JSON (with extra hidden character)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, parse-error

I'm using PHP's `json_encode()` to return some data, retrieved by jQuery's `ajax()`:

Simplified JS:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: './api/_imgdown.php',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
});
```

The PHP is:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
//default apiResponse
$apiResponse = [
    "status" => 1,
    "message" => "success",
    "data" => null
];
```

Then when php runs my code, it ends by adding this data:

```
$apiResponse['data'][] = [
    "mid" => (int)$mid,
    "card_type" => $card_type,
    "header_size" => (int)$headers['Content-Length'],
    "saved_size" => (int)filesize($imgSavePath),
    "saved_path" => $imgSavePath
];
//spit out the JSON
echo json_encode($apiResponse);
exit();
```

The JSON:

```
{"status":1,"message":"success","data":[{"mid":340052,"card_type":"kakusei","header_size":48337,"saved_size":48337,"saved_path":"..\/card\/kakusei\/340052.png"}]}
```

At first it seems valid. My Ajax that retrieves this PHP always ends with `parseerror` (thus going into the `error` part of `ajax()`).

If you copy and paste this JSON on http://jsonlint.com/, it says "Unexpected token " and http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ says is not valid.

I've tried `echo json_encode($apiResponse, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` even though escaping slashes is ok `\/` but made no difference.

**But what isn't exactly valid? Wasn't PHP supposed to return valid JSON?**

Extra info: Testing on Windows7, Chrome v28.XX, using PHP 5.4.XX on Apache

Questions I've read before actually posting this one:

- [json_encode creating malformed JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500834/json-encode-creating-malformed-json-data)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15654848/684932
- [about json_encode and ajax dataType: "json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809761/about-json-encode-and-ajax-datatype-json)
- [php json_encode not returning proper json encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518580/php-json-encode-not-returning-proper-json-encoded-string)

---

**Update:**

Copying from SO into JSONlint gives valid json. So I investigated a little further and noticed the PHP is creating a weird hidden character that is actually making json invalid. See below screenshot. How I fix that?
[image: json invalid character]

Comment: JSONLint shows it to be good.

Comment: your json is valid, and your php is valid.  My guess it's your ajax call.  Try using `$.getJSON` a simpler ajax call for requesting json

Comment: Its showing valid on jsonlint.

Comment: Valid on jsonformatter too.

Comment: Question: Can you try changing `$apiResponse['data'][] = [` to `$apiResponse['data'] = [` and see if it works better ? I don't understand why you are adding your `data` element as an array with another array inside, it should be fine being a single level array (unless you really need it).

Comment: Maybe you have some hidden characters in the string that jQuery chokes on.

Comment: do you have some text output before your php output

Comment: To everyone who added comment: Please read the **update**, I've found what is the real problem (that when pasting onto Stackoverflow actually 'fixed', therefore isn't invalid anymore).

Comment: @DevZer0 Nope, I've checked. line 1 starts with `<?php`, last line ends with `?>`, no extra spaces or anything.

Comment: It may be a BOM character but I have no idea why it is there... Could you determine the ASCII code of the first character in the return data? Use `console.log(data.charCodeAt(0))`.

Comment: @silkfire `65279`. And now that you said, the encoding I'm saving with my text editor is `utf-8 with bom` (because BOM accepts `áãà` and other stuff without I having to actually convert to the html entities). But testing saving the file as normal utf-8 worked (json is now really valid!). You have any idea what this first character is?

Comment: It could be that very BOM character indeed. But all my PHP files are always UTF-8 with BOM mark and I echo json all the time exactly like you do and I never get a problem. Encoding issues are always annoying :) I added it as a real answer :)

Comment: @Alex-Info.net Just to explain the `$apiResponse['data'][] = [`, 'data' will hold more items so this way the final json will be `"data":[ { /*one object*/ }, { /* another object*/}]`. I simplified my code but I have a loop that actually adds more stuff into the json but wasn't relevant to the problem so I removed for the sake of simplicity..

Comment: I am pretty sure the json-string is not encoded in the character set the character set your html document is expecting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be an issue with a BOM mark. Try to save the file as normal UTF-8 instead.

Comment: Yeah, as you helped find out, was the BOM char `65279`. I've found another question with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538203/how-to-avoid-echoing-character-65279-in-php-this-question-also-relates-to-java The problem is that I need the BOM since the `card_type` might have latin characters such as `áéã` which are not encoded into HTML entities thus bugging when saved without `BOM`. I'll save as normal UTF-8 and try use `htmlentities()` for that and hope to work. Thanks for your time answering!

Comment: Oh my God. Have searched for an answer for this issue for two days now... Thanks! :-)

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered same problem, but I could not find which file on my Windows is saved in UTF8 with BOM (Even though I have tried to search the files as many as I could).

However, I've found out the workaround.
Assuming on the server side I have

```
die(json_encode(array(
    'OK' => 1
)))
```

1. On the $.ajax call, I remove the entry "datatype : 'json'" and I access to the response with the following lines:

> ```
> success: function (response) {
>       var data = $.parseJSON(response); 
>       console.log(data.OK); // = 1
>   }
> ```

2. On the $.ajax call, I still keep the entry "datatype : 'json'", then I have to access the value inside the response like this

> var dataOK = response['OK']; // = 1